# ruby way - relative path

Tags: ruby, file, relative-path

I am using `File.read('file.txt')` in a ruby script. But I don't know what is the best way to create a correct relative path, I can do

```
File.read(File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/file.txt)
```

but I wonder if there a more beautiful way in ruby?

Comment: Your code looks fine. The only possible issue is the assumption of a forward slash, as explained below. If this is a *rails* project, for example, then you could also use `Rails.root` to define paths within the project.

Comment: This is why the [Pathname](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/pathname/rdoc/Pathname.html) gem exists.

Comment: This may be a duplicate, but it's not a duplicate of the linked question, since that doesn't deal with relative paths at all.

Answer (score 6):

There's a number of ways, but this one is the most flexible:

```
File.read(File.expand_path('file.txt', File.dirname(__FILE__))
```

You may also want to use `Dir.pwd` to be relative to the current working directory in your shell.

Note that using string concatenation for paths *may* work, but using `expand_path` or `join` is more reliable and properly handles platform differences, like on Windows where parts are natively joined with backslash instead.